# Spacing and size of my matrix displays

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, arrays, size

I am displeased with some of my display in the following equation :

```
\begin{frame}
        \begin{align*}
        \left[ \begin{array}{l}
        \dfrac{\partial \log L}{\partial b} \\ 
        \dfrac{\partial \log L}{\partial \sigma^2_u} 
        \end{array}\right]
        &= 
        \left[ \begin{array}{c}
        \dfrac{1}{\hat{\sigma}_u^2}X^T(y-X\hat{b}) \\ 
        - \dfrac{T}{2\hat{\sigma}^2_u}+\dfrac{1}{2\hat{\sigma}^4_u}(y-\textbf{X}    \hat{\textbf{b}})^T(y-\textbf{X}\hat{\textbf{b}})
        \end{array}\right]
        = \left[\begin{array}{l} 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]
        \end{align*}
\end{frame}
```

I get that : 
[image]

And I have two points of concern :

- I feel there should me a little more spacing between the two lines of my matrices (it is obivious because of $\sigma^2_u$ but even in the first matrix it is too little
- I would like the last matrix to be the same size as the other two

How could I achieve these two things ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to increase the array inter-line space by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}
        \left[ \begin{array}{l}
        \dfrac{\partial \log L}{\partial b} \\ 
        \dfrac{\partial \log L}{\partial \sigma^2_u} 
        \end{array}\right]
        = 
        \left[ \begin{array}{c}
        \dfrac{1}{\hat{\sigma}_u^2}X^T(y-X\hat{b}) \\ 
        - \dfrac{T}{2\hat{\sigma}^2_u}+\dfrac{1}{2\hat{\sigma}^4_u}(y-\textbf{X}    \hat{\textbf{b}})^T(y-\textbf{X}\hat{\textbf{b}})
        \end{array}\right]
        = \left[\begin{array}{l} 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another (better) option is to use a `bmatrix`:

```
\begin{equation*}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \dfrac{\partial \log L}{\partial b} \\ 
        \dfrac{\partial \log L}{\partial \sigma^2_u} 
        \end{bmatrix}
        = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \dfrac{1}{\hat{\sigma}_u^2}X^T(y-X\hat{b}) \\ 
        - \dfrac{T}{2\hat{\sigma}^2_u}+\dfrac{1}{2\hat{\sigma}^4_u}(y-\textbf{X}    \hat{\textbf{b}})^T(y-\textbf{X}\hat{\textbf{b}})
        \end{bmatrix}
        = 
        \begin{bmatrix} 
        \ 0\ \\ 0 
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: I was slowly figuring the initial choice of array was part of the problem. Thx for your solution. But don't you find in the second solution that the last matrix is a bit too narrow horizontally ? (I am sorry to be both asking for help and picky)

Comment: @Aerandal  - You can simply change one of the zeros in the last matrix to `\ 0 \ ` to thicken the matrix a bit.